# As a Nepali passport holder how can I extend my Non-Immigrant Visa "ED" for Thailand?

Tags: visas, thailand, nepali-citizens

27 years young Nepali boy, live in Thailand.

Comment: We don't know a lot about extending because Expats has more competence, please ask over there http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @pnuts yes I have Non-immigration visa"ED" and I want extend it for a year.

Comment: Mahidol University has a page about this [here](http://www.muic.mahidol.ac.th/eng/?page_id=2015). I do not know if this is a reputable university.